# Build Tools cannot be found

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to setup Android Studio to work with my previously made apps, but if I try to import a project from an old project via the .gradle file (made with the walkthrough of [this guide on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). But every time I try, I end up with the same error:

[image: error message]

Now, I tried reinstalling the SDK tools via the SDK manager, and I got the upgraded versions. My SDK manager looks like this:

[image: SDK manager]

So I would think it should be fully updated. The IDE log is somewhere  that I cannot find, so if that can help with solving the error, I would love to know where this is. Also, when I try to create a new project (not import from eclipse project), it gives me the following error:

[image]

That would be nice to have solved aswell.

I have set the JAVA_HOME variable, and I have also set the ANDROID_HOME variable. It was apparently needed to use the program.

Comment: I know in Eclipse, you had to manually set the android SDK location (within the IDE).  Have you tried this?

Comment: I have tried this, yes. There is the option to go into Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure and made a new pointer towards the SDK that follows with Android Studio, which is version 22.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and updating ADT in Eclipse solved it for me.  I know it sounds strange, but maybe give it a try?

Comment: Check that you have only one sdk folder. I had 3 in my pc. one is using a windows  installer and set to be only for my use (C:\username\appdata\local\android\) When I click sdk manager in android studio. it invokes the sdk at this location and not the sdk location I want android studio to use. (D:\sdk) probably has something to do with %PATH% system variable.

Answer (score 1):

The error for build tools revision 16 is very strange since the first revision of that component was 17. What does your build.gradle says? Make sure it says "17" for the buildToolsVersion property.

The other error makes it look like your Android Studio instance is pointing to an older SDK somewhere on your disk which is strange.